# What does having a "tremendous personality" mean?

Tags: idioms

Here I'll use it in a sentence:

> "It took people a while to get used to his tremendous personality"

What does that mean?

Comment: See [big personality](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Big+Personality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of

> **tremendous** personality

is slightly ambiguous.

It could mean the person is very outgoing, gregarious, loud, and will speak to or socialise with anyone.

It can also mean they have a really, really, nice character with a big heart, very generous, very considerate, always helpful: an **exceptional personality**.

> He's a great guy, really **tremendous**.

Though in the case of charity, it might usually be characterised as having a **tremendous heart**.

Comment: Are you assuming that only the colloquial meaning of tremendous is aooropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Well the definition of 'tremendous' is:

Very great in amount, scale, or intensity.

So they probably mean he has a very extreme personality. (Not calm, talks and acts in extremes, often times reckless.)

Or they could also mean that he has a large personality, which has a very similar meaning.

Comment: Does the definition depend on where you're from?

Comment: Is that definition of "tremendous" quoted from somewhere? It would be good to have attribution and quote formatting if so.

Comment: yeah, if you google that word then the definition comes up.

Comment: and that definition does not depend on where you are from.

Answer (score 0):

The definition in the Concise Oxford Dictionary is

```
Awe-inspiring, fearful, overpowering, (colloq.) remarkable, considerable, excellent
```

So the expression "tremendous personality" could mean (informally) that he is a great guy, or it could be a euphemism meaning that he is very strong-willed.

I doubt that it would "take people a while to get used to" a great guy, so I suspect that the latter might be the intended meaning.